# Zigzag order using `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10em, 1fr));`

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to layout a series of HTML siblings in a zig-zag order using a CSS grid. Each sibling should be the same size and the grid should use auto layout like `grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr))`.

I tried this auto layout:

```css
#div1 {  
  display:grid;   
  grid-gap:10px; 
  margin:30px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr) );
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
#div1 > DIV {
  padding: 30px;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div> 
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
</div>
```

I want to achieve the green layout, but got the red layout.

[image: Example-Image of zig-zag order]

Notice that the cells in the red layout are different in size and do not wrap to create a new set of rows.

ASCII art of desired layout, automatically adapting to the width of the viewport, e.g.:

```
 1  4
 2  5
 3  6
 7 10
 8 11
 9 12
etc
```

```
 1  4  7
 2  5  8
 3  6  9
10 13 16
11 14 17
12 15 18
```

```
 1  4  7 10
 2  5  8 11
 3  6  9 12
13 16
14 17
15 18
```

```
 1  4  7 10 13
 2  5  8 11 14
 3  6  9 12 15
16
17
18
```

*Constrains:*

- I can not change the HTML
- The auto layout should create as much equally wide columns as possible.

Comment: Can you make two separate grids, one for 1-9 one for the rest

Comment: always 3 columns?